# Do I need to call close on an mpsc channel, even if I drop both Sender and Receiver?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Consider the following example:

```
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (mut sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel::<u32>(32);
    sender.send(42).await.unwrap();

    std::mem::drop(sender);
    std::mem::drop(receiver);
}
```

Here I create an `mpsc` `Sender` / `Receiver` couple, I use `sender` to send a value, but I never receive that value on `receiver`. Then, **without** calling `close` on `receiver`, I drop both `sender` and `receiver`.

Tokio's [mpsc documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.12.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html) seems to state that dropping a `Receiver` without calling `close` and consuming all values is ill-advised, as values could linger forever in the channel without being dropped. I wonder if this applies to the above example, too. There I drop *both* the `Receiver` and all (i.e., the only) `Sender`s. I somehow have a hard time imagining this could cause a memory-leak, but I want to make sure if what I'm doing is safe.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the documentation is to advice good practice. It's fishy to have code that doesn't read all items produced. If you need a stop behavior it's should be implemented in the sender. The receiver should never stop by itself.

Close allow a middle ground by closing the receiver to prevent new message from the sender. Than the receiver can be read until there is no message, preventing any loose.

But there is no such requirement, you don't need to do it if you want. The drop implementation will clean memory anyway as we can see [here](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/f1b89675eb621edc23a9aa31d625270307fb6ce9/tokio/src/sync/mpsc/chan.rs#L316):

```rust
impl<T, S: Semaphore> Drop for Rx<T, S> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        use super::block::Read::Value;

        self.close();

        self.inner.rx_fields.with_mut(|rx_fields_ptr| {
            let rx_fields = unsafe { &mut *rx_fields_ptr };

            while let Some(Value(_)) = rx_fields.list.pop(&self.inner.tx) {
                self.inner.semaphore.add_permit();
            }
        })
    }
}
```